# Send stdout to file no tee

Tags: windows, stdout, tee

I am working on Windows XP, and I was wondering is there anyway to get the output from stdout and write it to a file. I need to be able to write to the console and a file, but using something like tee won't work.

My boss is working on an application that takes a while and he is writing to the console. At the end, he wants to rewind stdout for some lines and then write the output to a file. He believes that writing to file every time that something is written to the screen is too much I/O. I may be completely wrong, but isn't that how the tee command works? Stdout is piped into tee which then writes the output to the console and then the designated file.

Is this possible? I know that stdout is a file descriptor, so I was thinking that it should be possible because you can rewind other files, but is stdout write-only? I know in Unix that stdout is the file dev/stdout.

Thanks

Comment: You should get your boss to ask his own question.  Otherwise he won't understand how insane his plan is.

Answer (score 0):

This is what tee (or redirecting streams generally) is for.  Strictly speaking, you can't "rewind" stdout.  That's why you'd redirect it elsewhere if you needed to see its data later.

I am suspicious of the "it's too much IO to write to a file and to the console" assertion: to me that smacks of premature optimization.  However, assuming that is actually true...AND assuming you don't want to redirect your output, the only other choice I see is holding it in memory until you're ready to write it out.  You could come up with a fancy scheme which allocated a block of memory and wrote to it (and the console) then flushed it as it became full...but that seems like a lot of trouble to go to.

How much IO we talking here?

Comment: It is actually not a lot of I/O. The program just needs to be fast,but I don't think it will add too much time because the writes occur before and after computations. There are a few sprinkled in between. Tee would definitely solve his problem. The goal is essentially to be able to see the program as it runs and also have a copy for viewing later. I figured tee was probably the best bet, but I didn't know if my suggested alternative was simply unpopular or impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pipe to redirect stdout to a file. You can display the content of the file later.

Have a look at this example: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)